# Qt Designer .ui to .py conversion doesn't support on currentindexchange event for combobox

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt4, qt-designer, pyuic

I am working on `QT Designer` for the first time. I have created a combo box with IP address values in it `a.b.c.d` and `p.q.r.s`. I translated the `.ui` file created in `QT Designer` to `.py` file using `pyuic4` tool, so that it can be used in `Python` project that I am developing in `Visual Studio`.

Now when I run my `Python` project, the form is opened properly, but on the selection of any value in combobox/dropdown, it isn't displaying the selected value at the top although it shows the value as selected/highlighted when I see the complete list by clicking on dropdown again. `Python` code doesn't seem to contain `currentIndexChanged` properties.

Is this usual? Do I have to write the code for such a basic functionality manually?

I tried to write it manually using the code below but this also doesn't seem to be working:

```
self.IPAddress_comboBox.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(self.handleChanged)

def handleChanged(self, text):
 index= self.IPAddress_comboBox.findText(text,QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString) 
 if index >=0:
   self.IPAddress_comboBox.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

[image: Combobox with selected value as 10.200.25.11 but displayed value is 10.200.25.10]

Here I selected the value 10.200.25.11 which is displayed as highlighted but when the dropdown closes it displays 10.200.25.10 at the top. (while on qt designer, preview works fine)

Answer (score 1):

There should not be quotes around the signal argument type `QString`:

```
self.IPAddress_comboBox.currentIndexChanged[QString].connect(self.handleChanged)
```

I'm not sure why your combo box isn't displaying the selected value at the top; that functionality works for me.  If you could [provide an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that might help.

Comment: On Removing Quotes, I get the error 'QString' is not defined.

Comment: Did you import `QString`?
`from PyQt4.QtCore import QString`